# How to access variable set in service provider inside a config file?

Tags: php, laravel

I currently work on a admin panel where admins are allowed to modify some setting variables.

Until now I stored the values inside the `boot()` method of my "SettingServiceProvider" like this:

```
config()->set('sparkpost_secret', $setting->gets('general')->sparkpost_secret);
```

But, now, I need those variables inside `config/services.php` and I would try to set it like:

```
'sparkpost' => [
    'secret' => config('sparkpost_secret'),
],
```

but `config('sparkpost_secret')` returns null, while when I would try to access it inside any controller, the right value would be returned. It seems that the config files are loaded before the service providers are.

How can access a variable (created inside a provider) inside a config file?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the register method and everything should work fine and/or you can set `protected $defer = true;` to delay the loading of the serice provider

Comment: Unfortunately, it still returns `null`. I don't think the issue is about deferring the service provider, because it already gets loaded after the config files do. So, it wouldn't really make a difference, I believe.